# Why does pyramid give exception of zipimporter.get_filename()

Tags: python, pyramid

I am writing a simple pyramid application, and I try to run it `pserve development.ini`.

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/my/python/packages/.mytest/current/bin/pserve", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(pyramid.scripts.pserve.main())
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 316, in run
    global_conf=vars)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 340, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/util.py", line 58, in fix_call
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/compat.py", line 23, in reraise
    exec('raise t, e, tb', dict(t=t, e=e, tb=tb))
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/PasteDeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/at/mytest-1.9.0-py2.7.egg//mytest/__init__.py", line 108, in main
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/p/pyramid-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 930, in scan
    ignore=ignore)
  File "/users/is/pypi/egg_cache/v/venusian-1.0a7-py2.7.egg/venusian/__init__.py", line 187, in scan
    fn = loader.get_filename()
TypeError: zipimporter.get_filename() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

anyone could tell me how it comes?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I choose not to delete this question as I believe it might help other people who have the same problems.

Basically `venusian` does not support *zipped egg*. So when you produce your egg for pyramid, do not do it as zip egg.

Comment: hmm - I opened an issue on that problem once https://github.com/Pylons/venusian/issues/19 it's still open (almost 2 years), but it does not seem like someone is likely to change anything there soon